# How do I derive a regular grammars from this regular expression?

Tags: regex

How do I derive a regular grammars from this regular expression?

```
(a or b)*ba(ba)*
```

I'm stuck with the last part
so

```
S -> A | B | C
A -> aA | bA
B -> bC
C -> cD
D->bE ?
E->af | ^ ?
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: This question might get more love on the [Computer Science StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They don't have regexp-grammars tag

Comment: A little explanation of what you are trying to achieve and what your productions mean would help make this a better question. For example, if c is a terminal symbol in `C -> cD` why is it not in your regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *S* → `(a + b)* b a (b a)*`

The initial `(a + b)*` gives three possibilities: it can expand to `a (a + b)*`, or it can expand to `b (a + b)*`, or it can be empty:

- *S* → `a (a + b)* b a (b a)*` = *aS*
- *S* → `b (a + b)* b a (b a)*` = *bS*
- *S* → `b a (b a)*` = *A*

For *A*, the initial `b a` is fully constrained, so we clearly must write:

- *A* → `b a (b a)*` = *bB*
- *B* → `a (b a)*` = *aC*

For *C*, `(b a)*` gives two possibilities: it can expand to `b a (b a)*`, or it can be empty:

- *C* → `b a (b a)*` = *bB*
- *C* → ε

(Using the fact that `a (b a)*` matched a non-terminal we'd already defined. Failing that, we could instead have written:

- *C* → `b a (b a)*` = *bD*
- *D* → `a (b a)*` = *aC*
- *C* → ε

.)

Putting it together:

- *S* → *aS*
- *S* → *bS*
- *S* → *A*
- *A* → *bB*
- *B* → *aC*
- *C* → *bB*
- *C* → ε